# PHP date returned incorrectly

Tags: php

I am pulling a date value from a MySQL DB formatted as `01/20/13` I am calling the PHP date function on this value returned to get what day of the week it is, so `01/20/13` is today's date which is Sunday but it keeps returning the value Wednesday. I have included the code below I am new to programming so this is probably a stupid error I am overlooking.

```
<?php

        require '../TimeCard/DB.php';

    try{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `date` FROM `timeRecords` WHERE `employeeID`= 1 ');
    $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
  {
    echo date("l", $row['date']) . "<br>";
    echo $row['date'] . "<br>";
  }

        ?>
```

Comment: In my MySQL applications I tend to prefer storing either MySQL dates or UNIX timestamps as opposed to human readable dates because MySQL dates are very easy to work with in SQL, and UNIX timestamps are very easy to work with in PHP. ...Just for future reference. I feel most developers would probably agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql does not store dates as m/d/y it stores them as Y-m-d you're mysql database will turn "01/20/13" into 0000-00-00.

However, if you are not using the date type, and storing as a string use

```
strtotime($row['date'])
```

Answer (score 1):

use strtotime on your mysql stored date, then use the date function on it

```
$day = date('l',strtotime($row['date']));
```

Answer (score 1):

try with [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo date("l", strtotime($row['date'])) . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function is an integer timestamp. You'd have better luck using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), eg

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $row['date']);
echo $dt->format('l');
```

This gives you the added bonus of tailoring the date parser to match your source format rather than relying on `strtotime()` which definitely has its quirks such as treating dates with forward-slashes (10/12/13) as US (12th October) vs dates with hyphens (10-12-13) as EU (10th December)

Example here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/iVXxA1

Comment: i have a question, can we have to enable any library to use this class `DateTime`?